# Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName returns incorrect value for Outlook on a Mac

Tags: office-js

When using OfficeJS to determine what office client is being used, I am calling  `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName` but am given `Outlook` for users on Outlook for Mac when I expect to get `Mac Outlook`

According to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.md, the possible values for the `hostname` can be `Outlook`, `Mac Outlook`, `OutlookIOS`, or `OutlookWebApp`

I am using the latest OfficeJs from https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

Comment: Thanks for reporting; I passed it along to the team.

Comment: The documentation URL has changed to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/1.1/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs) has been changed to remove any mention of `Mac Outlook`. It now suggests that the output will be `Outlook` when on a Mac client.

Answer (score 0):

We are working to fix this issue. Meanwhile, as a workaround you can use useragent in your add in to identify the browser. We will let you know as soon as this issue is fixed.

Comment: I haven't heard anything in 9 months, is there some other place I should be asking for this to be looked into?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use Browser UserAngent to detect add-in is running on Outlook App for Mac.

```html
Office.initialize = function () {
    //if Add-in is opening in Outlook App for MAC.
    var OutlookHost = Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName;
    var platform = navigator.platform;
    if (OutlookHost !== null && OutlookHost !== undefined && OutlookHost === "Outlook" && platform != null && platform.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

navigator.platform will return:

```
"MacIntel"
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand there is a way to find out ways to know the OS in JavaScript, this was an issue with the documented properties withing OfficeJS.